# Swift Package Manager with multiple target executables?

Tags: c, swift, makefile

Does anyone know whether the Swift Package Manager has any support for generating multiple executables from in one package?  I have a C program that needs to be migrated to Swift, and it is currently packaged as a makefile with multiple targets.  I am struggling a bit with how that might map to a Swift package, or is it 'packages'?

Answer (score 2):

Yes:

```
project/
project/Sources/foo/main.swift
project/Sources/bar/main.swift
```

Will generate two executables, one `foo`, one `bar`.

There is [documentation here](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/tree/main/Documentation).

Comment: Swift docs got reorganizes shortly after @mxcl's answer, and the link doesn't work any more. Furthermore, from the [current docs](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Documentation/PackageDescription.md), it's not clear that the package manager infers modules simply from paths it sees, as the emphasis is entirely on `Package.swift`. I would guess that you define multiple executable `product`s there, each with one or more associated `target`s that get bundled into the executable.

Answer (score 0):

Yeap, you can do that, however requires kind of a workaround:

So you have your package structure (shortened of course):

```
- Package
-- Sources
--- Executables
---- Executable_One
----- main.swift
---- Executable_Two
----- main.swift
```

If you arrange it this way and try to launch the app, Xcode will fire 'Overlapping sources...' error, cause you have two files named "main.swift".

To fix that, you go to Package.swift and declare both of your executables as `executableTarget` and exclude other executable from each of them:

```
let package = Package(
...
targets: [
...
.executableTarget(
   name: "Executable_One",
   path: "Sources/Executables",
   exclude: ["Executable_Two"]
),
.executableTarget(
    name: "Executable_Two",
    path: "Sources/Executables",
    exclude: ["Executable_One"]
),
...
]
```

Might be tricky but works.